# MySQL changing int range (7-9) into value of 8 and averaging

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE HrsPerWk_avg
  SELECT CrsTitle, AVG(HoursPerWkincClass)
  FROM FCQ GROUP BY CrsTitle;
```

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '7-9'

So I want to average all the hours per week, but my data is in the form 7-9, 10-12, ect.  How can I get values that will average 7-9 as (8) and 10-12 as (11)?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
HoursPerWkInclClass
7-9
4-6
7-9
7-9
10-12
10-12
7-9
10-12
4-6
16+
```

When added `(8+5+8+8+11+11+8+11+5+16)=91/10=9.1`

This is exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Take a look at this one: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: better give your table, some sample data , wished result , and it will be easy to help u

Comment: What's with that `16+`? Do you have other values like that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your range values are single ranges, rather than comma-separated lists for example, you'll need to perform some [substring operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to retrieve the values on either side of `-` and average them manually with arithmetic.  `AVG()` is an aggregate function, and cannot be used for this purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE HrsPerWk_avg
SELECT
  CrsTitle,
  /* Extract the min/max values with substring operations, add them, divide by 2 */
  /* SUBSTRING_INDEX() gets the first value before - */
  (SUBSTRING_INDEX(HoursPerWkincClass, '-', 1) +
  /* SUBSTR() and LOCATE() get the second value after - */
  /* Both are added and divided by 2 */
  SUBSTR(HoursPerWkincClass, LOCATE('-', HoursPerWkincClass)+1)) / 2
FROM FCQ 
GROUP BY CrsTitle
```

Here's a sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96510/2

#### Update

To support a value like `16+` as you have posted above, you will need to match values like that using `LOCATE()` conditionally, and trim off the `+` with a substring operation.

```
SELECT
  CrsTitle,
  CASE
    /* Remove + if present */
    WHEN LOCATE('+', HoursPerWkincClass) >= 1 THEN REPLACE(HoursPerWkincClass, '+', '')
    ELSE
      /* Otherwise use the range finding stuff from above... */
      (SUBSTRING_INDEX(HoursPerWkincClass, '-', 1) +
      SUBSTR(HoursPerWkincClass, LOCATE('-', HoursPerWkincClass)+1)) / 2
  END AS the_avg
FROM FCQ
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdd43/2

Comment: Thank you very much.  All that was missing is an AS statement. Other than that, well done sir.

Comment: @user2027275 But what about that `16+` you have in your data you just posted above? This won't support a value like that. If you have other values like that it will need additional work.

Comment: @user2027275 There - I added some logic to trim off `+` if present, and otherwise find the range average.